# Asp.net: 'application/grpc-web' is not supported

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, grpc, code-first, grpc-web

I had Asp.net core and gRPC working on the browser...but now I get:

```
info: Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler[2]
  Request content-type of 'application/grpc-web' is not supported.
```

Any ideas on how to track this down?

Comment: Have you done any changes to the project and then this started to happen or did all this just happen by it self all of the sudden?

Comment: I believe it's because of some changes I made.

Comment: Ok @Ray, I believe you have to give up some more info to have any chance of help..

Comment: Wish I could've given more info that would have been useful. I was looking for more diagnostics that would point to the problem.  Like listing supported content-types, etc...  Anyway, I found the problem: I called app.UseEndpoints() twice is...bad?

Comment: BTW: I've added a unit test that catches this kinda error quicker.

Answer (score 16):

Likely an issue in your `Startup.cs`

Yours should look something like this
[image]

My guess is that you are missing `app.UseGrpcWeb()` or the `EnabledGrpc()` on the EndpointConventionBuilder

Comment: You saved my day!  
The only thing that I needed to change here are cors settings and to set it like here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Answer (score 7):

I ran across this issue. I had my `app.UseGrpcWeb();` before `app.UseRouting();`

It had to be after.

So correct order is:

```
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseGrpcWeb();
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/browser?view=aspnetcore-5.0 -- "**Configure gRPC-Web in ASP.NET Core**"